# many MSQL_XP waits

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, extended-stored-procedure

I've run the script from Paul Randal: [please tell me where it hurts](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/wait-statistics-or-please-tell-me-where-it-hurts/), and the top wait type (by 32 %) is MSQL_XP.

When running sp_whoisactive, I've seen calls to xp_sqljdbc_xa_commit, xp_sqljdbc_xa_start and xp_sqljdbc_xa_end.

I do not know much about this server, except that it runs a 3rd party application, that our users complain is very slow. I've tried to google about these commands and the wait type, but found hardly anything (except about a 3rd party backup tool). The system is programmed in Java, and runs on both SQL Server and Oracle. We're one of the few users on SQL Server.

The SQL code that is running on the server, is doing a lot of reads. The server has plenty of RAM so most of the reads are in-memory. I think the tables are over-indexed (with single-column indexes), and have plans to change that somewhat.

Is there anything else I can do to make the server run faster?

Comment: It's not the server problem but a problem with distributed transactions. Maybe you should upgrade your jdbc driver to the latest version. Read this article, perhaps it will help to find some solution: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/understanding-xa-transactions?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @DenisRubashkin; the link suggests upgrading, and we have done so, when we installed a new SQL Server 2017 on new hardware. Thank you.

Comment: @DenisRubashkin; But your comment made me think; would it be a good idea to pick another JDBC driver?

Comment: This is not necessarily a problem with the driver. It can be a problem inside the 3rd party app which starts too long XA Transactions. I haven't been had to dip in solving the same problems. If I had to do so, I would try to find out which particular transactions are so long and then why.

Comment: @DenisRubashkin; You comment made me think; the 3rd party app could be running long, because it is waiting for the SQL Server?

Comment: Status a year later: The MSQL_XP waits went down when we improved the indexing on the biggest table, so that we were not getting warnings about "Risidual IO". It turned out we were table scanning the biggest table on almost every query.